# Ensure required install actions for a dll are executed without duplicating code

Tags: c#, installation, setup-project, nested

I have a c# solution with two regular projects and a setup project. One of the regular projects is an executable, while the other is a dll, that I also use in other solutions. The dll project relies on there being a certain event log source, that it can log to, and since the program is intended to be run by users that are not allowed to create log sources, this source must be created at installation.

I have done this by creating an installer class for my executable project, creating the log source in the installer, and included that installer in my custom actions in the setup project. This works, but now I have to create a similar installer for every other project, that also uses that dll.

The best solution would be, if I could write an installer for the dll, and then choose the dll for the custom actions in the setup project. This way I would only have to state the log creation requirement once. However, I am not able to select the dll project output for the custom actions in the setup project.

Another good solution would be, if I could somehow specify that the installer for the executable should be transitive, such that it would also perform install actions for any projects that the executable project depended on, but I don't know how to specify that requirement.

So what can I do to avoid duplicating installation code between different projects?

Comment: how about creating the event log source programatically from the one that wants to write to it, the dll? (instead of all the setup project and installer mess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add an installer class to your DLL then register the DLL for execution of custom actions in a setup project.  If you have tried this and encountered problems, could you please be more specific about which version of Visual Studio and which type of setup project you are using?

Comment: Ah, I can indeed do this. My problem before was, that I had not included the dll project output in the setup project, and somehow I had gotten it into my head, that since the dll project was not executable, I would not be able to do so. Sometimes, all it takes is for someone to say that something is easy to do, and then one can see the solution immediately. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just have a MyApplication.Installation assembly where I put a custom action that creates the event source. All my setup projects reference this assembly and invoke its custom action.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? You create a simple batch file or a powershell script to create the log file that you want to create.You could make an installer for the dll file(or even the entire solution it doesn't matter.) You can then invoke the batch file that you just wrote from the installer.[Refer [here]](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=Q111515) . This way, you are not duplicating the creation logic for a dependent files/resources; and you can use the same batch file for multiple setup projects basically(provided they use the same resources.)

I hope this answers your question. 
One step further, what environment are your clients on? Are they still on Win XP(SP2 or before)? If that is the case, you have to do something similar to what you already have in mind right now. However, if that is not the case, if your clients are on Win 7, You could use nuget to publish your bins(Refer [here](http://preview.docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package)). I admit that this is still looked at as a source code sharing solution. But I believe that the approach can be extended to publishing binaries too.